# Realm Swift Nested Recursive list is not saving data properly

Tags: ios, swift, realm, codable, realm-list

Ok so I have a Realm model that has a RealmList of itself(recursive). Upon decoding via Decodable in swift it shows perfect when I debug but when it is saved to Realm it is not saved properly. Only tabs are stored, no columns and fields are stored. Following is my Model(have removed few properties of int or string type):

```
class Workflow : Object, Codable {

@objc dynamic var workflowId = 0
@objc dynamic var fieldName : String? = nil
@objc dynamic var fieldValue : String? = nil

let tabs = List<Workflow>()
let columns = List<Workflow>()
let fields = List<Workflow>()

private enum CodingKeys : String,CodingKey {
    case id = "tenantFieldSetupId"
    case fieldName = "fieldName"
    case fieldLabel = "fieldLabel"

    case tabs = "tabs"

    case fields = "fields"
    case columns = "columns"



}
 public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    self.init()

    do{
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.workflowId = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: . workflowId) ?? Constants.defaultRealmInt

        self.fieldName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String?.self, forKey: .fieldName) ?? Constants.defaultRealmIdString

        self.fieldLabel = try container.decodeIfPresent(String?.self, forKey: .fieldLabel) ?? Constants.defaultRealmIdString



        let tempTabs = try container.decodeIfPresent([Workflow].self, forKey: .tabs) ?? []
        self.tabs.append(objectsIn:tempTabs)

        let tempFields = try container.decodeIfPresent([Workflow].self, forKey: .fields) ?? []
        self.fields.append(objectsIn:tempFields)

        let tempColumns = try container.decodeIfPresent([Workflow].self, forKey: .columns) ?? []
        self.columns.append(objectsIn:tempColumns)
    }
    catch{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

This is the method in which I am passing the json to convert it into Workflow object:

```
func jsonToObject <T: Decodable> (jsonString: String) -> T? {
    if let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) {
        return self.jsonToObject(jsonData: data)
    }
    return nil
}
```

They array of Workflow is returned perfectly, from the above method. I pass the array to the method below which I used to save it into Realm DB(its actually list of Workflows). It works with no error. But when I check the DB The list of Workflows are different. No fields and columns

```
 private func  insertOrUpdateList<T : Object> (list : Array<T>, update : Bool) -> Bool { // Run when primary key is defined in Model

     return autoreleasepool { () -> Bool in
         let realm = getRealm()

         if realm.isInWriteTransaction {
         // logging that realm is in write transaction
             return false
         }else{
             realm.beginWrite()
            realm.add(list,update: update ? .modified: .all)
             do {
                 try realm.commitWrite()
                 return true
             }catch let err {
                 return false
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Talib, can you please share more code so we can help you better?

Comment: @rs7 done, have provided all the necessary details

Comment: You need to track why it's only saving tabs. You could use print statements for that. For example, add a print statement for when realm is in a write transaction, and print out the error when committing write doesn't work. Does that make sense? Once you do that, please share that information here and hopefully we can figure out what's going on.

Comment: @rs7 no error occurs

Comment: Understood. Then it must be that the realm is in a write transaction?

Comment: As I mentioned, that is does not cause any error. It stores the Object model in RealmDB but when I see the the DB, the JSON and the storedData are different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203183/discussion-between-talib-shabbir-hussain-and-rs7).